# How to update the app during execution in the browserstack using appium?

Tags: selenium, appium, browserstack

This is the sample code for the APP update in a normal way,
@RunWith(JUnit4.class)
public class Edition009_Android_Upgrade {

```
private String APP_PKG = "io.cloudgrey.the_app";
private String APP_ACT = "com.theapp.MainActivity";

private String APP_V1_0_0 = "https://github.com/cloudgrey-io/the-app/releases/download/v1.0.0/TheApp-v1.0.0.apk";
private String APP_V1_0_1 = "https://github.com/cloudgrey-io/the-app/releases/download/v1.0.1/TheApp-v1.0.1.apk";
private String APP_V1_0_2 = "https://github.com/cloudgrey-io/the-app/releases/download/v1.0.2/TheApp-v1.0.2.apk";


private String TEST_MESSAGE = "Hello World";

private By msgInput = MobileBy.AccessibilityId("messageInput");
private By savedMsg = MobileBy.AccessibilityId(TEST_MESSAGE);
private By saveMsgBtn = MobileBy.AccessibilityId("messageSaveBtn");
private By echoBox = MobileBy.AccessibilityId("Echo Box");

@Test
public void testSavedTextAfterUpgrade () throws IOException {
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

    capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Android Emulator");
    capabilities.setCapability("automationName", "UiAutomator2");
    capabilities.setCapability("app", APP_V1_0_0);

    // change this to APP_V1_0_1 to experience a failing scenario
    String appUpgradeVersion = APP_V1_0_2;

    // Open the app.
    AndroidDriver driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

    try {
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(echoBox)).click();
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(msgInput)).sendKeys(TEST_MESSAGE);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(saveMsgBtn)).click();
        String savedText = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(savedMsg)).getText();
        Assert.assertEquals(savedText, TEST_MESSAGE);

        driver.installApp(appUpgradeVersion);
        Activity activity = new Activity(APP_PKG, APP_ACT);
        driver.startActivity(activity);

        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(echoBox)).click();
        savedText = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(savedMsg)).getText();
        Assert.assertEquals(savedText, TEST_MESSAGE);
    } finally {
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

}

Please help me to get the browser stack set up for this scenario where I need to update the app in between

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to achieve this. It is still a workaround at the moment and the flow is being worked upon.

**Step 1**: Upload both versions of the App using the REST API. Do note down the hash ID for each version.
​

refer: https://www.browserstack.com/docs/app-automate/api-reference
​

**Step 2**: The app(s) required mid-session needs to be uploaded before starting the session. In this step, the app is only uploaded but not pre-installed on the device.
​

specify the `app` capability as the primary app (lower version):

​
`"app": "bs://<hash-ad>"`

**Step 3**: Specify the app(s) to be used in the session inside the `otherApps` capability. This would be the newer version of the app:
​

`"otherApps" : ["bs://<hash-id-of-newer-app>","bs://<hash-id-of-newer-app>"]`

If the bundle id is the same, we won't install the apps before the start of the session but actual installation will happen, when you call
`installApp("bs://hashed-id")` command.
​

**Step 4**: In the middle of the session, you can run `installApp("bs://hashed-id")` command and pass the app_url that was sent in the `otherApps` capability.
​

```
driver.installApp("bs://<hashed-id-of-newer-app>");
Activity activity = new Activity(APP_PKG, APP_ACT);
driver.startActivity(activity);
```

This is a workaround at the moment. We are working on optimizing this workflow.

You can directly reach out to support@browserstack.com in case you have queries around this.

---

**Update:**

BrowserStack now supports the workflow to test App Upgrade in the session.

https://www.browserstack.com/docs/app-automate/appium/advanced-features/test-app-upgrades